# Is there a way to print the structure of a multi-module maven project?

Tags: maven, printing, structure, pretty-print, multi-module

I'm facing a rather large multi module maven project. I would like to see how the root (parent) project is composed out of subprojects/  child projects in the form of groupId:artifactId (possible with some identation to reflect the hierarchy.

Of course I can write my own plugin to get this printout, but I reckon that there must be something available of the shelf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello late answer but I have added a plugin into maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.qunix</groupId>
    <artifactId>structure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To run the plugin you will need to add into your pom as below:

```
<build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.qunix</groupId>
                <artifactId>structure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                                printModules
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

then output will look like:

```
   [INFO] --- structure-maven-plugin:0.0.1:printModules (default) @ test ---
[INFO] 

Project structure (all modules):



                test
                |
                |__ a
                |
                |__ b
                |
                |
                \__ c
                    |
                    |__ d
                    |
                    |__ e
                    |
                    |__ f
```

If you want to print all files insted of modules use the goal: **printAll** or if you want just folders use the goal:**printFolders**. `<inherited>` means dont execute plugin also in modules and `<ignore>` mean skip this files using regex pattern.

EDIT: there is never version you can pull from github: https://github.com/buraksarac/MavenStructurePlugin

Comment: This plugin is awesome! You're the best.

Comment: @javajavajava I am glad it helped:)

Comment: @HRgiger great work! This is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for my (very) late reply.

Comment: Thank you for the plugin @HRgiger. However, I would be wary with using plugin as it has two major vulnerabilities. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.qunix/structure-maven-plugin/0.0.2
Could you address them in 0.0.2?
However, it seems 0.0.1 has no vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encounter such plugin so far nor even heard about one. Google doesn't know about it too, so it's likely you have to write own plugin or try to parse `mvn dependency:tree` or just reactor build order, probably using heavily console output streaming and so.

Answer (score 0):

I think that mvn `dependency:tree` is way to go.

You should try this :

```
mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=target/dependencies.txt
cat target/dependencies.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1":"$2}'
```

That way, you will have a nice dependency tree with indentation but without scope, version and type :)

Comment: Thanks. But I meant it in the opposite direction. Yes, you can print the dependencies of a sub component by means of tree. However, can you also collect all dependencies required by the root project (that is constituted of sub components)?